# Using comma in ng-tags-input value

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, ng-tags-input

I am using ng-tags-input with autocomplete.  Some of my autocomplete values have commas in them.  When a user selects an autocomplete value which has a comma, it splits it into multiple tags on the comma.  Is there a way to have this show up as one tag?
For example, my autocomplete shows `Mike, Jim` and when the user clicks on that, it will split it into two tags: `Mike` and `Jim`.  I want it to be one tag - `Mike, Jim`

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a plunker showing your problem? You can use [this template](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:Y7cuEGojnyGLbsUXJL1k).

Comment: I think I tracked it down.  Bower was pulling version 2.1 and it seems to work fine with 2.3

Answer (score 2):

It is easy, add this attribute in you HTML

```
add-on-comma="false"
```

[see for more detail](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/api)

Comment: is it possible to add on semicolon ? i mean when we type multiple values seperated with semicolon can create as tags ?